# видеофон html css

Tags: html, css, видео

Помогите, пожалуйста, добавил скрипт видеофона, отображается только в IE и Mozilla, в Opere и Chrome просто стоит видео, хотя есть форматы видео .mp4 .ogg .webm

```
<script>                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
  var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('body'), {
    "align": "centerXY",
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 720,
    "path": "video/",
    "filename": "bg",
    "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"],
    "preload": true,
    "autoplay": true,
    "loop": true
  });
  $("a[rel='m_PageScroll2id']").mPageScroll2id();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить "muted": true в параметры скрипта. У движка Blink, на котором основан и хром и опера, есть такая особенность, они не будут автоматически проигрывать видео со звуком (независимо от того, есть он на самом деле или нет)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var videobackground = new $.backgroundVideo($('body'), {
    "align": "centerXY",
    "width": 1280,
    "height": 720,
    "path": "video/",
    "filename": "bg",
    "types": ["mp4","ogg","webm"],
    "preload": true,
    "autoplay": true,
    "loop": true,
    "muted": true
  });
  $("a[rel='m_PageScroll2id']").mPageScroll2id();
});
```

Comment: не помогло(((((